# grep will not work in bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

I am new to this so this might seem like a dumb question but I just can not get this code to work. It appears that the grep is looking for the variable name and not its value. Thanks any help is appriciated.

```
    if [ "$file" == "osi_OpenInterest" ]
    then
        count=`cat timestamps.txt | grep "${file}" | grep "${currdate}" | grep "07:" | grep "AM" | wc -l`
        if [ $count -eq 0 ];
        then
           echo "$file not found" | mail -s "RetrieverB Missing File" "$email"
        fi
    fi
```

Comment: it's impossible to answer this question in its current form. which part do you have problems with? `echo "X${file}X${currdate}X";` come up with concrete example, without variables, content of the timestamps file, and expected output.

Comment: timestamps.txt contains:                                            **12-04-2012  07:30AM             15028622 osi_OpenInterest**
and that is the expected output of of the grep statement so count would be 1. from what i can tell the greps appear to be actualling searching for ${file} and not **osi_OpenInterest** same thing with the ${currdate} should be looking for **12-04-2012** and not "${currdate}

Comment: I asked you to verify the contents of your variables. don't come up with wild assumptions ("it's looking for ${currdate}")

Comment: Xosi_OpenInterestX12-04-12X

Comment: Not related to your actual question, just a coding suggestion: if the only thing you do with $count is check to see if it's zero, you can simplify the test. grep's exit status depends on whether it found a match, so you can use it directly in the if statement (with a -q to suppress output): `if grep "${file}" timestamps.txt | grep "${currdate}" | grep "07:" | grep -q "AM"; then ...` (I also removed a [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat))

Comment: you should be able to reduce the number of greps in the pipeline with `grep -e "${file}" -e  "${currdate}" -e "07:" -e "AM"` (untested) or `grep "$currdate 07:[0-9][0-9]AM .* $file"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currdate` is `12-04-12`. Your file contains the date in a different format, `12-04-2012`, so there's no match.

Comment: Thank You. I completley overlooked that i have been staring at theis program for hours. It has 20 if else statments that have the same issue when if declared currdate instead of date +%m-%d-%Y I used date +%m-%d-%y